# PHP: Paypal Buy Now button not redirecting

Tags: php, paypal-sandbox

I am testing out Buy Now Button in Sandbox mode. I have setting successful/cancel urls in form parameters. After successful transaction it's not automatically redirecting to my success out but instead of it show screen with details and then text "Go to Reseller Store" which is linked to the URL of my success page. How do I make it to redirect itself so that I can ask customers for next step?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a setting within PayPal.

Log into PayPal with your business account and go to the Website Payment Preferences page.  This url works for me: https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/uk/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_profile-website-payments

Set your Return URL to the success page of your website, and set the Auto Return radio group to On.  Save the settings and it should work.

Comment: I am facing an issue, the page is now redirecting but it's not sending any data in return. As per this article, if auto return is enabled in settings then it does not send any data. https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/forums/basic-website-payments/getting-payment-data-paypal-auto-return-pdt-ipn-demystified?page=0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C1

Comment: For the reasons stated in the linked article, you should be using Instant Payment Notification to transfer the payment data back to Magento.  This happens as a separate request so it is unaffected by user actions like prematurely closing the browser.